# react using a param as function strict mode typescript error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Below code is fine if the strict mode of typescript is turned off

```
import * as React from "react";

const Form = ({ add }) => (
  <div
    onClick={() =>
      add({ //warning here
        a: 1,
        b: 2
      })
    }
  >
    Add
  </div>
);

export default Form;
```

But it will throw warning (Binding element 'add' implicitly has an 'any') because I didn't specify the type for the `add function`, any clue how to resolve that?

https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-snowflake-0up5q

Comment: You need to add type for props (e.g. `const Form = ({ add }: { add: Function })`)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
const Form = ({ add }: {add: any}) => (
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Form from "./Form";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const add = ({a,b} : { a: any, b: any}, ) => {
    console.log("a+b", a + b);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form add={add} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you should provide types for the Form component.
For example, something like this:

```
const Form = ({ add }: FormProps) => (/* here is your component implementation /*)
```

And FormProps looks like this:

```
interface FormProps {
  add: (terms: AddTerms) => void
}

/* 
  personally, I don't like to set type of Any,
  and I would set A and B to number explicitly 
  but is a matter of taste
*/
interface AddTerms {
  a: any,
  b: any
}
```

Next, in the app Component, provide types for add argument:

```
const add = ({ a, b }: {a: any, b: any}) => {
  console.log("a+b", a + b);
};
```

or import the AddTerms interface from Form component module

```
const add = ({ a, b }: AddTerms) => {
  console.log("a+b", a + b);
};
```

Comment: what is the difference between interface and type in react term?

Comment: I believe, there is no special meaning for interface and type in React. I personally prefer interfaces to types for specifying complex structures, which contains more than one value (e.g. - React Component props). Interfaces can be extended by other interfaces (useful for passing props in compositional components). For simple types (unions, generic or just aliases for long utility types) I prefer using types. Sorry for mistakes, I am not a native speaker. Anyway, for the better understanding you should check [official docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)